# Div centering within SVG tag

Tags: html, css, svg

Hope somebody can educate me about CSS and styling tricks.

**What I want to Achieve**: ***Positioning of the div with class name redDiv at the centre of svg tag*** just by using css.

Please see the sample code snippet on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinayak_nandi/CDmGQ/2657/)

I have a div with class myDiv and inside that I have a tag called  and a another div with class name redDiv after svg.

HTML snippet

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <svg style ="background-color: blue;
        margin: 70px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;">
    </svg>
    <div class="redDiv"></div>
</div>
```

and my CSS has following stylings:

```
.myDiv{
    background-color: Yellow;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.redDiv{
    background-color: #F00;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**I would like the redDiv to be at the centre of svg tag.**

**Please note**

1. The height and width property of svg tag can very, that means svg can be a square or a rectangle. Also svg tag is not having any ID or class attribute ans I dont want to add one!
2. Please do not position the redDiv relative to myDiv
3. You  can change/add extra CSS property to redDiv

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed width of svg, maybe:

```
position:absolute;
top:140px;
left:140px;
```

will help.

http://jsfiddle.net/CDmGQ/2664/

Comment: the above solution wont work if the height and width of the svg changes!! Height and width of SVG tag is dynamic, it could vary!! http://jsfiddle.net/vinayak_nandi/CDmGQ/2667/

Comment: Yes, I know. That's why I wrote "if you have fixed width of svg".

Comment: No Alex, Height and width of SVG are dynamic. It can not be a fixed width!